# WCF Datacontract - Does it support nullable data member?

Tags: wcf

```
    [DataMember]
    public int? NumberOfPages;   //////////// Is this supported????
    [DataMember]
    public bool? Color;          //////////// Is this supported????
    [DataMember]
    public int? BulkQuantity;
    [DataMember]
```

Comment: If you use [MessageHeader], you need [MessageBodyMember] for nullables. But I think with DataMember it should be fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, of course!

You should have no trouble whatsoever to create nullable data members, they'll be handled in the resulting WSDL/XSD as "xs:nillable=true" members. No problem at all.

Comment: But when i am doing that and testing it using WCF Test client , it says that "This operation is not supported by WCF Test client".

Comment: maybe it's just the WCF test client that can't handle it! Try writing your own little client to call a single function and get back that information.

Comment: marc_s is right; the web page lets you test a service from within a browser only supports primitive data types as parameters. This does not harm the service's functionality. If you don't want to write your own tool, try MS WCF Test Client (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, please see [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx):

> Nullable types are fully supported by the data contract serializer.

Answer (score 4):

@Kahoon and Batwad:

We solved this problem by using the `nullable<>` or `?` type in two steps:

1. In the class containing the generic field, define the field as follows:

   ```
   nullable<GenType> MyField {get; set;}
   ```
2. In the data contract that uses this baseclass, you can define which elements are known to the serializer/deserializer using some annotation-like tags. Here, we defined for example:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [DataContract]
   [KnownType(typeof(BaseClass<nullable<DateTime>>))]
   ```

   Instead of `BaseClass<nullable<DateTime>>` you can use `BaseClass<DateTime?>`, I think.

After this, the serialization of generic null values worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

In my case It looks like that the Nullable Integer passed in is treated as **Empty String** and NOT **Null Value**

So here is how I handle the nullable in the code

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? NumberOfPagesCount{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("NumberOfPages")]
    public string NumberOfPagesText
    {
        get { return this.NumberOfPagesCount.HasValue ? this.NumberOfPagesCount.Value.ToString("F2") : string.Empty; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                this.NumberOfPagesCount= Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
            else
            {
                this.NumberOfPagesCount= null;
            }
        }
    }
```